Outlook integration failing in FusionAuth
Integration with outlook is not working and the debug messages aren't useful. There are no logs that I can reference so the only error message is the one shown on the GUI. Turning off authentication is not a debugging option.

Host: outlook.office365.com
Security: TLS (unable to test without due to outlook restrictions)
Debug Enabled: ✔

Error in GUI:
Unable to send email via JavaMail

Prime Messaging Exception
Cause: MessagingException: Exception reading response

Any options to get more verbose logging?
